# corpus method in r

Tags: r, corpus

I am new to R.I am trying to know about `Corpus()` method.

This is the code i wrote.

```
library(tm)
my_obj<-"learning about corpus method"
corp<-Corpus(VectorSource(my_obj))
corp
```

I thought the output of this code should be the structured text  that is prepared by the `Corpus` method. But the output is :-

```
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 1
```

Can someone explain what corpus method does in **R** ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435054/how-to-show-corpus-text-in-r-tm-package

Answer (score 0):

the Corpus method make a collection of texts(called corpus in NLP), that enable user to use lots of text mining functions on it, for example tm-map function can remove punctuation, stop words, space, numbers ... , and you can count term frequency of each document in a corpus by using DocumentTermMatix function on corpus.